# How do we call applications implementing only the view and controller parts from the MVC pattern?

Tags: struts, ejb-3.0, struts-1

I am currently building guidelines and standards for my team. We build two types of applications:

- Business Web Applications using Java + MVC2 (EJB3, Struts and JSP) for transactions, scalability and persistence.
- Light Web Applications using Java + Struts and JSP for small applications like surveys, small forms, etc. Basically, it's like MVC2 without the model part of it.

I am looking for the right pattern or practice name for the Light Web Applications. I guess "View-Controller" could do the trick but I am trying to find a diagram that would illustrator that "pattern" properly.

Any idea?

Comment: Well, there is a model: the database. We just don't implement Java Beans (EJB Entity Beans and Session Beans).

Comment: Maybe http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this question.